# How to keep filecontents* from getting confused when it encloses \begin{document}..\end{document}?

Tags: external-files

I TeX the following code with `pdflatex --shell-escape` but the compilation got paused because of an error as the produced `prepare.tex` does not contain `\end{document}`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{filecontents*}{prepare.tex}
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[active,tightpage,graphics]{preview}
\PreviewBorder=0pt

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
    \only<1>{\includegraphics{example-image-a}}
    \only<2>{\includegraphics{example-image-b}}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
\end{filecontents*}


\usepackage{animate}
\begin{document}
    \immediate\write18{pdflatex.exe prepare.tex}
    \animategraphics{10}{prepare.pdf}{}{}
\end{document}
```

How to keep `filecontents*` from getting confused when it encloses `\begin{document}..\end{document}`?

Bonus question (rather than I create a new question for it): How can I force `filecontents` to override the specified file if it already exists?

Edit: Actually there is no problem with `filecontents`. The source of problem is the extension `.pdf` in the `\animategraphics`. Now unfortunately, the title is misleading.

Comment: The bonus answer: Load the package `filecontents`.

Comment: There is no problem with the `prepare.tex` file as per your MWE. It gets created properly.  Have a look at that file with a text editor.

Comment: The package `mwe` is needed to get the graphics `example-image-a` and `example-image-b`

Comment: @MarcoDaniel: No need, `graphicx` already provides us with them out of the box I think.

Comment: you don't need to load `mwe` into the document but you need to have installed `mwe` (or at least extracted the images from the mwe distribution and placed them in the input path)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: Yes. I agree. The default TeXLive installation did it out of the box.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following example works.

My changes

1. The argument of `\animategraphics` must NOT have a file extension.
2. I load the package `filecontents` to answer your bonus question.

Here the mwe:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{filecontents*}{prepare.tex}
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[active,tightpage,graphics]{preview}
\PreviewBorder=0pt

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
    \only<1>{\includegraphics{example-image-a}}
    \only<2>{\includegraphics{example-image-b}}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
\end{filecontents*}


\usepackage{animate}
\begin{document}
    \immediate\write18{pdflatex.exe prepare.tex}
    \animategraphics{10}{prepare}{}{}% <======= MUST NOT HAVE EXTENSION!
\end{document}
```

<sub>tested with Ubuntu+TeXLive</sub>